# How NOT to use *.ui Files for creating Forms

Tags: c++, qt4

I'm experimenting with QT4 and would like to use the QT-Creator for gaining a better understanding for creating forms directly in C++.

But it only creates *.ui-Files and keeps the Code untouched. Is there a way not to use the UI-Files?

Comment: Yes. Instead of designer create your forms in c++ code by creating a widget then adding widgets to the widget in some layout then connecting your signals and slots. This can be a lot of work but is perfectly fine for a small example.

Comment: And is there a way to do it with a designer?

Comment: I am confused why having .ui files is such a bad thing. However with some work I can see someone modifying the source code (remember with Qt all source code is provided) of the designer executable to run uic automatically from the designer. This would still have the ui file though but produce c++ source. To do this without a ui file totally it would be significantly more difficult if you expect to be able to make a form then change it at a later date. Designer then would have to understand the generated c++ code to be able to change it.

Comment: I want to learn how to create form by using plain C++ and how to extend it during its run-time. 
For that issue UI-Files are no help at all

Comment: Then you can't use the designer to create your form. Manually create your widgets and layouts using c++ code you created.

Comment: that's the question I asked: Is there a way to generate the necessary C++-Code with any designer?

Comment: Not directly. Although again you can still use designer to make a .ui file and have uic generate c++. This does not in any way prevent you from extending the form at runtime or even deleting the ui file and using the generated c++ from then on.